# Remove text between 1 regex and 1 string

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I'm trying to remove all text between an email regex, and a specific "word/string".

Example data:

```
    Linus@techtips.com:123rwefwrekfwsei983:93qfujri249tu-ewrgifhjn:Speaker$500$
```

My purpose is to remove/slice/purge everything between the `EmailRegex:` and `Speaker`
So the desired output would be:   `Linus@techtips.com:Speaker$500$`

The email regex will always be the same, but the string will sometimes differentiate if I have to use it for other things in the future.

The email regex I use is: `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}`

I have not tried anything myself so far, as I'm inexperienced with this. Just to note there's millions of lines, and my preference is using GNU/Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk. Use `:` as input and output field separator and print first and last column:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{print $1,$NF}' file
```

Output:

```
Linus@techtips.com:Speaker$500$
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. This format isn't always the same as sometimes there's multiple colons being the delimiters. Therefore this would work for the example I shown, but not lines which contain numerous colons. Sorry again.

Comment: Okay, fix your example.

Comment: Wait, I'm wrong, it worked perfectly. But I'm unsure how it worked lol, can you explain how this command works?

Comment: It splits your row with `:` in four columns and outputs first and last column.

Comment: Interesting, that's nice to know, thankyou!, your answer is perfect for me.